# Unpivot in pandas using a column that have mutiple value columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

So i have a dataframe frame like this

| index | type_of_product | dt_of_product | value_of_product | size_of_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/02/22 | 23.1 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 01/03/22 | 23.2 | 2 |
| 1 | C | 01/04/22 | 23.3 | 2 |

And i need to unpivot the colum `type_of_product` with the values of `dt_of_product`, `value_of_product` and `size_of_product`

I tryed to use
 `pd.pivot(df,  index = "index", column = "type_of_product", values = ["dt_of_product","value_of_product","size_of_product"]`

and want to get this desire output

| index | A_dt_of_product | B_dt_of_product | C_dt_of_product | A_value_of_product | B_value_of_product | C_value_of_product | A_size_of_product | B_size_of_product | C_size_of_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/22 | 01/03/22 | 01/04/22 | 23.1 | 23.2 | 23.3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Is there a way to do this in pandas with one pivot or do i have to do 3 pivots and merges all on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = df.pivot(index='index', 
              values=['dt_of_product', 'value_of_product', 'size_of_product'], 
              columns = ['type_of_product'])
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0).map('_'.join)
```

Comment: Jesus you're a genius @SomeDude i never stop being amazed by the community of stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = (
    df.set_index(["index", "type_of_product"])
    .unstack(level=1)
    .swaplevel(axis=1)
)
df.columns = map("_".join, df.columns)
print(df.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| index | A_dt_of_product | B_dt_of_product | C_dt_of_product | A_value_of_product | B_value_of_product | C_value_of_product | A_size_of_product | B_size_of_product | C_size_of_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/22 | 01/03/22 | 01/04/22 | 23.1 | 23.2 | 23.3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

You could try `set_index` with `unstack`

```
s = df.set_index(['index','type_of_product']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
s
Out[30]: 
      A_dt_of_product  A_size_of_product  ...  C_size_of_product C_value_of_product
index                                     ...                                      
1            01/02/22                  1  ...                  2               23.3
[1 rows x 9 columns]
```